# Install Go 1.2 onto Nitrous.io

Tags: go, nitrousio

I'm trying to install Go onto my Nitrous.io box from source.
The Nitrous supplied Go Box has version 1.1.2 of Go, and I would like to use 1.2.

Having checked out the source and compiled, the build fails when running the tests.  It seems there is not enough memory to run them concurrently on the box.

It's the same problem as this one in April:
https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5342
The patch mentioned there to make the tests run sequentially, did not apply cleanly, so am unsure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have compiled Go on Nitrous successfully. Don't run the tests (compiling with all.bash), just compile Go (with make.bash) and it will work fine. I replaced the old Go (in ~/.go) and decompressed the Go source in ~/.go, and then compiled it. No need to change the $PATH.